# foreach loop takes too long in SharePoint 2010

Tags: performance, sharepoint, collections, foreach

I'm trying to retrieve synonyms from SharePoint 2010, and my code has the following issue: it loops through a `keywordCollection` that has no indexer. Doing a `foreach` takes too long, because instantiating a new keyword lasts about 5-10ms and having around 8000keywords so far, it takes about 80 seconds to complete.
Things that I've tried so far:

- get the enumerator -> takes 80 seconds as well
- cast the collection into a list -> fails for unknown reason.

Code sample:

```
KeywordContext keywordContext = fastProxy.KeywordContext;
SearchSettingGroupCollection searchSettingGroupCollection = keywordContext.SearchSettingGroups;

foreach (SearchSettingGroup searchSettingGroup in searchSettingGroupCollection)
{
    if (searchSettingGroup.Name == siteId.ToString())
    {
        foreach (Keyword keyword in searchSettingGroup.Keywords)
        {
            //the rest of the work here, per total takes about 470ms
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to loop through a collection without using a `foreach` statement, which instantiates a new `object<T>` every time?

Thanks!

Comment: "`// the rest of the work here`" <---- This is the most relevant part. What do you do inside the loop? How would having an indexer help you?

Comment: //the rest of the work -> just some string manipulation which per total takes 470 ms out of those 80seconds. Problem is that whenever foreach instantiates a new readonly keyword, it takes like 10ms which is my problem.

Comment: So it is not like you can skip most of the keywords, right? i.e. it looks like your code needs to access each keyword there is in the collection, correct?

Comment: exactly, I need a way to access every keyword in that collection without instantiating a new one like "foreach" does

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl))
{
    // get the site ID
    var guid = site.ID.ToString();

    // code to get the fastProxy FASTAdminProxy

    KeywordContext keywordContext = fastProxy.KeywordContext;
    var ssgs = keywordContext.SearchSettingGroups;
    if (ssgs.ContainsSearchSettingGroup(guid))
    {
        var searchSettingGroup = ssgs.GetSearchSettingGroup(guid);
        foreach (var keyWord in searchSettingGroup.Keywords)
        {
            // do stuff with keyWord.Synonyms
        }
    }
}
```

Also, although I can't test it at the moment, you could try using the  [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// ...

Keyword[] array = new Keyword[searchSettingGroup.Keywords.Count];
searchSettingGroup.Keywords.CopyTo(array, 0);
Parallel.ForEach<Keyword>(array, keyword =>
{
    //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: There's no difference between what you did there and what I did. My problem is with foreach, behind the scene is doing something like (var keyword = new keyword blabla....) that instantiation is taking like 10ms per keyword.

Comment: For your second approach, I already tried CopyTo but it fails, and I can not use parallel library since its compiled with .NET 3.5. Sadly I will have to deal with it or find another approach.

Comment: And getting the enumerator(which should be the same as CopyTo, because they need to create a new instance of that collection with all keywords in it) took 80 seconds as well, so in theory, even if it worked, it would have taken the same ENORMOUS amount of time to copy them into a string[]

Comment: May I ask, why do you need to get all the synonyms in the first place?

Comment: Just doing something that Microsoft abandoned for 2010, the Synonyms to work properly. It's actually part of my job, so I just have to

Comment: Are you trying to add synonyms to the keywords?

Comment: Trying to create a dictionary with them, then use them for some other thing

Comment: Is it feasible to cache this dictionary?